# How to update the div text based on dropdown value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 dropdowns, 2 for the "From" destination and 2 for the "To" destination.
What I want to do is to update the #from div and the #to div based on the dropdown values.

For example on the "From" destination, if 1 and 5 is selected then the #from must show `1 -> 5`

That means that while selecting the 1, it will show `1 ->` until the user selects from the 2nd dropdown and it completes the sequence.

```
from
<select id="from_country">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="from_city">
    <option value="1">4</option>
    <option value="2">5</option>
    <option value="3">6</option>
</select>
<br>
<br />
to
<select id="to_country">
    <option value="1">7</option>
    <option value="2">8</option>
    <option value="3">9</option>
</select>

<select id="to_city">
    <option value="1">10</option>
    <option value="2">11</option>
    <option value="3">12</option>
</select>

<div id="from"></div>
<div id="to"></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uafrzqyo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#from_country').change(function () {
    var country = $('option:selected', this).val();
    var city = $('#from_city').val();
    $('#from').text(country + "->" + city);

})
$('#from_city').change(function () {
    var city = $('option:selected', this).val();
    var country = $('#from_country').val();
    $('#from').text(country + "->" + city);

})


$('#to_country').change(function () {
    var country = $('option:selected', this).val();
    var city = $('#to_city').val();

    console.log(country + "->" + city)
    $('#to').text(country + "->" + city);

})
$('#to_city').change(function () {
    var city = $('option:selected', this).val();
    var country = $('#to_country').val();
    $('#to').text(country + "->" + city);

})
```

Try this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e8pfza1j/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
$('#from_country').change(function () {
    $('#from').text( $('#from_country :selected').text() + '->' +
 $('#from_city :selected').text());
    });

$('#from_city').change(function () {
    $('#from').text( $('#from_country :selected').text() + '->' +
 $('#from_city :selected').text());
    });

$('#to_country').change(function () {
    $('#to').text( $('#to_country :selected').text() + '->' +
 $('#to_city :selected').text());
    });

$('#to_city').change(function () {
    $('#to').text( $('#to_country :selected').text() + '->' +
 $('#to_city :selected').text());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution: http://jsbin.com/huvilegeso/edit?html,js,output. I only did it for the From section. The To section is very similar.

```
var from = [null, '->'];

$('#from_country').on('change', function() {
  from[0] = $(this).val();
  renderFrom(from);
});

$('#from_city').on('change', function() {
  from[2] = $(this).val();
  renderFrom(from);
});

function renderFrom(from) {
  $('#from').html(from.join(' '));
}
```